# pasar datos de html a variable como python

Tags: javascript, html, python, ajax

tengo unas entradas en html

```
<label for="fname">valor 1:</label> <input type="text" id="From">
<label for="fname">valor 2:</label> <input type="text" id="to">
<button type="submit" name = "range" ></button>
```

el codigo ajax

```
<script>

$('#range').click(function(){
    var From = $('#From').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
});

$.ajax({
    url:"/range",
    method:"POST",
    data: {From:From, to:to},
    
});
```

y el de python

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
if request.method == 'POST':
    From = request.form['from']
    to = request.form['to']
    print(From)
    print(to)
```

que mas me hace falta para lograr que lo que ponga en los imput se valla a python para usarlo como una variable???

simplemente no hace nada no me imprime en python lo que yo puse en el input del html. obviamente algo falta para lograr eso

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Y por el contrario: por qué dices que no funciona? Qué pasa cuando usas el código? Algún error? QUé pasa cuando revisas el contenido del request en python al recibirlo? Completa tu pregunta yendo a [edit], por favor :)

Comment: cuando no funciona que es lo que sucede; hay algun error en consola en el log de errores del sevidor???

Comment: Lo que hace falta es el atributo `name` en cada `input`, por ejemplo: `<input name="from" ... >`. De lo contrario no se enviará hacia el back. Saludos